# How can I loop through a list and change the values in it?

Tags: python, list

I am trying to run this simple code:

```
def looping(list_):

    for i in list_:
        list_[i]=8

    return list_
    
_list=[1,2,3,4,5,6]

print(looping(_list))
```

I define a function looping(). I pass a list as argument and the function should return an amended list. I want to loop and change all values of the list to 8.

But it says it is wrong why?

Comment: I think 6 is out of bounds, so it throws an IndexError? *But it says it is wrong why?* please include the error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `i` in your loop is not the index. It's the value you get from the list.

If you want to access & assign your list items with the index, you want something like this:

```py
def looping(list_):

    for i in range(len(list_)):
        list_[i]=8

    return list_
    
_list=[1,2,3,4,5,6]

print(looping(_list))
```

Output:

> [8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8]